# Puppet Run Stages with sub modules

Tags: puppet

I am learning Puppet and have taken their "Getting Started with Puppet" class but it did not cover Run Stages, and their documentation on Run Stages is thin.

I need to make sure that two things happen before anything else that Puppet does. I have been advised by the instructor of my "Getting Started with Puppet" class to look at Run Stages.

In my investigation of Run Stages, I have learned that the puppetlabs-stdlib class sets up some "standard" Run Stages. One of them being "setup". As shown in the snippet below I have implemented the `stage => 'setup'` as per https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_run_stages.html. However, I am getting errors from Puppet:

```
root@server:~# puppet agent -t
Info: Using configured environment 'dev_branch'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Retrieving locales
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: 
Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Could not find stage setup specified by 
Class[Vpn::Roles::Vpn::Client] (file:
```

/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/wal_prod1910_dev/modules/bh/manifests/roles/snaplocker.pp, line: 5, column: 3) on node server
    Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
    Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Looking at the error message and the Puppet documentation, I have added quotations around the various string values and replaced my initial `->` with  the correct `=>`, but I still get the same error.

```
class bh::roles::snaplocker()
{
  # stage => setup takes advantage of the setup run stage introduced by
  #  puppetlabs-stdlib which is pulled in by puppet-control-bh/Puppetfile
  class { 'vpn::roles::vpn::client': stage => 'setup' }

  class { 'bh::profiles::move_archives': stage => 'setup' }

  #...
}
```

Looking more closely at the error message, I believe that the cause is that `puppetlabs-stdlib` id introduced by the `Puppetfile` in the class that calls the module that I am working on. I have been deliberately avoiding trying to pull in `puppetlabs-stdlib` in the class I am working on to avoid duplication. But apparently I need it... The module I am working on does not have a `Puppetfile` do I need to somehow include `puppetlabs-stdlib` in my sub module? If so how should I do that? If not, how to I tell my sub module to use the instance declared in the parent module's `Puppetfile`?

Comment: Did you declare the stages you are assigning (as documented at: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_run_stages.html#custom-stages)? `main` is the only stage that exists by default if I recall correctly.

Comment: In trying to understand the project that I inherited I noticed that in the top level module the Puppetfile pulls in puppetlabs-stdlib and in investigating that I noticed that it contains a stages.pp file that defines the setup stage and assumed that I could use that.

Comment: @cptully, it is very important to understand the difference between an installed module making classes *available* to you on one hand and actually *using* those classes in your manifests on the other.  This is fundamental to how Puppet enables you to configure different machines differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you don't need any `stage` if you have correct classes/resources dependencies.

From the ["Run stages" documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_run_stages.html):

> CAUTION: Due to these limitations, use stages with the simplest of classes, and only when absolutely necessary. A valid use case is mass dependencies like package repositories.

In your case, if you really want stages, you should add `include stdlib::stages`[[1](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_run_stages.html)](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/master/manifests/stages.pp) or explicitly add stage like `stage { 'setup': }`